# Python Configparser cannot find section under Unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, configparser

So I have to test a Config file. In this Config file a ConfigParser instance will be initialized then load a config file.

In the Unittest I imported this parser file then tried to read a node of this ConfigParse instance. But then it raises a error that it cannot find the section.

Howcome? Is there a way to fix it?

edited:
So the Unittest just imported the Config file. The name of the config file is called config. the instance is called p_config In a test case the instance will be called like:

```
config.p_config.get('section1','a')
```

The Config file look pretty standard.

```
import ConfigParser
p_config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
p_config.read("xxx.cfg")
```

so my config file looks pretty much like a normal windows config:

```
[section1]
a = 1
b = 2
[section2]
c = 2
d = 4
```

The error it raised just says it cannot find section:

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'section1'
```

The content of the UnitTest:

```
class TestConfigFile(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


    def test_example(self):
        print global_path_config.get('section1', 'a')
```

Comment: Precise your question with your code ? ;) If you want to use ConfigParser instead of json config.

Comment: @glegoux Hi, I updated it.

Comment: Can you post your configparser code (where you read the file) and the exact error message as well?

Comment: and what is your code causing errors? and where is error's traceback?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it just raised a errro and says it cannot find the section. if traces back to earlier frames it shows actually the call of the get() function caused this error.

Comment: What is `config` and how is it created? Please post your unit test. Your parser code doesn't seem to be the issue here, it works. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @chrki config is the name of the config file.

Comment: @T.F. I don't understand, you are using `config` here, not as a string/filename or whatever: `config.p_config.get('section1','a')` -- Have yout tried `print p_config.get('section1','a')`?

Comment: @chrki yes. actually this configparser instance works well in other files of the whole project, cause writing UnitTest is the last step of this whole project. But in Unittest it seems something is wrong with it. I am wondering why.

Comment: @T.F. Post your unit test then please, stripped down to the minimum needed to run it.

Comment: @chrki updated. actually just a easiest frame. but failed to read the content from the parser.

Comment: @T.F. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting test config object up without actually providing a configuration file for your test to read.

I assume you are using the python unittest module.

How does your command line differ from running your project and running your tests?  The command line may be an issue.

For example, if you use `python /path/to/file.py <--options> config.ini` to launch your program and `python -m unittest /path/to/config/unittest -v` to launch your unit tests, then your configuration file is never being read.

In `setUp(self):` you would need to initialize the object with the config file location.  I prefer to write a short, fake config file in `setUp` so I can easily remove it in `tearDown` and know exactly how it is related to my tests without polluting my working configuration file.